# Angular 5 loop array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, ngfor

I am really a beginner in angular ionic and stuff. Here, my problem is I have tried using `*ngFor` to iterate someArr and pass to `[something]=""` but my page became blank after adding it. Can someone help me.

```js
someArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

```html
<ion-content>

  <myHeader *ngIf="qArr.length && qArr[cPg].letter === 'A'" [something]="">
  </myHeader>

  <myHeader *ngIf="qArr.length && qArr[cPg].letter === 'B'" [something]="">
  </myHeader>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: if your page is blank, the myHeader component is not passing the ngif check. what is qArr? can we see it?

Comment: qArr is an array, qArr = [{"name": "Abu"}, {"origin": "Pakistan"}, ...]

Comment: i have already tried using ng-container also didnt work

Comment: I'm assuming that myHeader is a custom component that you created. Can we see that component?

Comment: Can you edit your question and explain what you are trying to accomplish? It would help us to explain the solution or recommend a more efficient approach.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show what you've tried with ngFor? 
Should looks something like this

```
<div *ngFor="let val of someArr">
  {{val}}
</div>
```

Sidenote, you cannot combine ngFor and ngIf inside same tag
meaning this will not work

```
<div *ngFor="let val of someArr" *ngIf="val === 1">
  {{val}}
</div>
```

But this would work

```
<div *ngFor="let val of someArr">
  <div *ngIf="val === 1">
  {{val}}
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update**

something is not a real attribute, so we have no idea what you're refering to.
However you should be able to assign values to attribute. Take `id` attribute for instance

```
<div *ngFor="let val of someArr">
  <div  [id]="val">
  {{val}}
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: i added *ngFor="let s of someArr" and [something]="s". I wanted to pass 1 2 3 4 5 6 in [something]

Comment: thank you for helping anyway. i will try to change double quote to {}

Comment: @noorayu, that should work, something else is wrong (no pun intended)

Comment: i have changed something to result to be more meaningful. is it ok if im not using div, i used my component myHeader

Comment: Should be fine .

Answer (score 0):

When using ngFor you are creating local variable based on a class variable so you will have something like :

```
<div *ngFor="let item of someArr"></div>
```

where someArr is the class var = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

So inside your div, you will have access to each item using this :

```
<div *ngFor="let item of someArr">
   <p *ngIf="item === myFunction(item)"> {{ item }} </p>
</div>
```